# How to contact Apple about connection issue on bugreport.apple.com?

Tags: developer-program, bug

I have been trying to log into their bug reporter system (bugreport.apple.com) for about a month.

Every time I log in, I get redirected to an error page, which tell me to report the problem. The thing is, I have reported the problem through the email-address they provided in the error page and also through the "Report Login Issue"-link at the login page.

I have only received an automated message, which tell me they received the message and I haven't got any other update (and I still can't log in).

I have waited almost a month, what should I do?

Here's a screenshot of the error I get when I log in:

[image]

Comment: Exact same thing here. Same error, tried to contact them in both channels, and all I got was the automated messages (tried 3 times). I also don't know what else to do.

Comment: It's working for me now, although I had the same problem a month ago. You could try loggin in with a non developer Apple ID (Just a guess / Maybe worth a try).

Comment: @voidStem I still have the problem. Do you know if it's possible to get an other Apple ID without having to purchase something from Apple.

Comment: Have you write about this issues to their [forums](https://discussions.apple.com/index.jspa)?

Comment: @HoLyVieR it is possible using iTunes. Just sign out and register new account.

Comment: I just tried login with a brand new account and it tells me I have to register has an Apple Developer. Which brings me back to the original case, I have a developer account and I can't log in with it.

Comment: @HoLyVieR they just answered my e-mail after almost a month. They simply said "it's fixed" and now it's working. No details, but it was certainly on their end.

Comment: I'm curious if any of you are still having this issue. I've tried using Chrome/Safari on OSX 10.7, 10.9 and my iPhone, etc., but I'm only ever greeted by this error. I've emailed devbugs@apple.com but have received no reply or resolution. My iOS/OSX developer account is active and works everywhere else it's needed.

Comment: @somethingkindawierd From my understanding, it just takes a lot of time once you have emailed them. I haven't got any respond too, but it finished by working 2-4 months after.

Answer (score 3):

I tried connecting with Safari (6.0.2), and it wasn't working:

[image]

When using Chrome (versions 15 & 25), I am asked to sign-in using my Apple ID on this page: http://bugreport.apple.com/

I have no problem at all:

[image: A screenshot of the login-page]

Make sure you are using the latest update of your browser. Or use a different one such as Opera, Firefox, etc.

Take note of this, from the page, where you enter your Apple ID credentials:

> Note: Safari is the suggested browser for use of the Bug Reporter.
>   JavaScript and Cookies must be enabled to access the Bug Reporter.
>   Idle time to disconnect is 120 minutes.

If you have tried with different browsers, and it still doesn't work. I suggest you try repairing disk permissions in your disk utility, if you are on a Mac.

If it still does not work, try [downloading the newest Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/), and reinstall it. You can also try this link to the login-page.

Comment: I do have the latest version of Chrome at home and I also have v17 (dev channel) at work. I also tried with Safari  Windows (v5) at work. I also have to same issue when I try to login in with Safari (Ipod Touch). That's so far 3 different machine and setup I have tried to log in with.

Comment: It is very strange, I just tried on my iPhone 4, and logged in without any trouble. Can you try this url instead of the original?: https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn

Comment: Well that's the sign in page I get redirected to, when you go to bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Are you certain your developer license hasn't expired? And have you also tried this link: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/bugrptform.html taken from: http://developer.apple.com/support/resources/bug-reporting.html

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how the Apple Developer program works, but I registered few months ago, so I don't think it has expired. I'll give it a go with the bug report form, since all I want to do is report a bug to them. And just how of curiosity where have you been able to find that form ?

Comment: Well for now, I'll just hope, they review bug report from that form and that the bug will eventually get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the form on this page: [Bug Reporter Connection Problems - Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/noconnect.html)?

Comment: Yes, it's the `Report Login Issue` link on the bug report main page that I mentionned in my original post. I still haven't got any reply after a month.